# How to avoid class level @path in web service to handle all web service calls

Tags: java, web-services

I am writing a web service like

```
@Path("/pathName")
public class LoginServiceComponent {

   @GET
   @Path("/methodPathName/{param}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String getVoterByVoterId(  @PathParam("param")  String param)
    {
    .................

    }
}
```

Here my url to access web service is  http://www.abc.com/pathName/methodPathName/1

Here i have 10 methods.Is there any possibility to remove class level `@Path` means i have only one web service class in my project.So i dont want to use class level `@Param` repeatedly.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid the @Path on the class so your URL's don't have the "pathName" in the path, I don't think you can remove the @Path on the class entirely. But I have used the @Path class annotation of @Path("/") and was able to get just URL to be just http://www.abc.com/methodPathName/1 (if that's what you're trying to do).